# Are there kanijis in もういちどあねがいします

Tags: kanji

Are there usually any kanjis written in following the sentence

もういちどあねがいします - Please once again

My textbook only rarely uses any kanjis and I was wondering how this sentence would really/usually be written in Japanese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

もういちどあねがいします seems a misspelling of もういちどおねがいします.

もういちどおねがいします is written in kanjis as もう一度お願いします.